# How do you add an array as multiple columns into a data frame in pandas?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe

How do you add an array as multiple columns into a data frame in pandas? Here's what I've been trying to do, but so far it hasn't work.

```
c = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]] 
c = pd.DataFrame(c)
c
```

Output:

```
    0   1
0   1   2
1   3   4
2   5   6
```

```
b = ['d', 'dd', 'ddd']
ar = [[2345, 432, 532],
      [42, 345, 451],
      [436, 7656, 53]]
c[b] = ar

c
```

Output:

KeyError: "None of [Index(['d', 'dd', 'ddd'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"

The alternative way I can think of is making a data frame out of `b` and `ar`, then combining it together with `c`, but it would result in a bigger headache for me as the project in the long run.

Any advice on how to make this work?

Edit:
Ok, so basically my pandas is outdated. After updating my problem is solved. Thank you.

Comment: I cannot reproduce, what pandas version are you using?

Comment: tested in `pandas 1.1.3` and working well

Comment: @DaniMesejo This error comes in `pandas==1.0.5` I tested